# Tomcat threads != JVM threads?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, threadpool

The Tomcat Manager reports a different thread count than ThreadMXBean.  The number of threads reported by ThreadMXBean is the same as the number of threads reported in the YourKit profiler as well.  Is there a difference between Tomcat threads and JVM threads?

Line from Tomcat Manager:
Max threads: 200 Current thread count: 7 Current thread busy: 3

ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount():
38

Comment: Thanks for quick answers.  Your answers make complete sense :)

Answer (score 6):

Tomcat thread are *request processing* threads, and does not count other thread that the application may have started.

For a better look on what those other thread are, take a look at [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

According to the javadocs, [`ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadCount()):

> Returns the current number of live threads including both daemon and
>   non-daemon threads.

Therefore, the JVM could very well have 38 different threads going (mostly in the background). Tomcat makes a new thread for each request (so that it can have concurrent communication). It would make sense that these two numbers could differ.